# Android shawing installed apps as installed

Tags: android, error-handling, installation, apk

I have installed some apks from adb but when  try to install newer versions I get error already installed, when I look into my phone I get this:

Why this is happening, how to fix it, how to uninstall them?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgokn.png]

because of this I am not able to install new version. Not uninstall old versions

To make stackoverflow bot fool: (ignoore)

`I am writing a standard question`

Comment: it is strange, but you can try the following command:
adb uninstall [package name]

Comment: can you write the full adb command that you use to install apps?

Comment: @Dara I fixed it by deleting th data  from `/data/app` then rebooting

Comment: @helleye I fixed it by deleting th data from /data/app then rebooting